# Android Launching or bringing to front another application via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, launch, intentfilter

Im having trouble getting this to work, here´s a quick overview of the idea.

First, I cant change the logic behind this, it was a specific requirement from the customer, I realize that with any tool such as AnyCut it could be bypassed but that doesnt matter really.

My customer offers a suite of apps, the idea is that all applications bellonging to the suite would be launched from a "Dashboard app", so that I only show the Dashboard app in the main launcher and not all app icons.

Lets take two Apps to get the idea solved. The Dashboard App (A) and the Recieving App (B).

I want to establish an intent filter (I think) on app B so that whenever I go into app A, and click the app B icon the app will be either launched or started from where it let of (brought to front).

Is this even possible? If so, how can I do it? I managed to get it to launch by specifically launching one activity in the app using:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("PACKAGE_NAME","SPECIFIC_CLASS");
startActivity(i);
```

But that isnt the behaviour that I want, as it always starts app B in the same spot.

Thanx in advance,
                Stefano

Edit: Added some new information. I was taking a look at the DDMS.

If I launch the application from scratch through the main Android launcher the intent is exactly the same as when I leave the home button pressed and then only bring the app to front, what ever activity im in. So I was trying to reproduce, unsucsesfully until now, this intent.

```
INFO/ActivityManager(1292): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.package/.uiPackage.Activity}
```

This is how AnyCut does it

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.package/.uiPackage.Activity bnds=[125,242][235,360]}
```

Any idea how I could go about creating that exact same intent? I cant even find that flag in the Intent API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out, this is how I did it.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.example.package/com.example.package.activityName"));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: This is interesting. Will this actually take you back to where you left off in the secondary apps launched from the primary app (dashboard)? If so, this is good stuff to know!

Comment: @ice911 It does exacty what you describe, it seems android pulls up the app in the state it was. I tested this on the emulator, a nexus one a g2 and a galaxy tab and it works on all of them. 

The `activityName` im referring to is the one marked as main in the Manifest.

Comment: Amazing. Works like a charm.

Comment: Also works just fine with PendingIntents, e.g. for notifications: `PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0)`

Comment: @blindstuff I am sending data with the intent but unable to get intent data on second app. Is anything, I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I'm following the expected results you want to see, but the following would launch the app from the dashboard and remove the dashboard from the activity stack leaving the selected app running:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("PACKAGE_NAME","SPECIFIC_CLASS");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

I believe this should start the app as if you were starting any other app.

Please add more information on your logic if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for sorry, I would like not to specify the class I want to open, rather just invoke the other app in what ever activity it left off.

Comment: I would like the user to be able to be using the application, but for example when he clicks home, then go back into the dashboard and continue to use the app where it was.

Comment: `rather just invoke the other app in what ever activity it left off` That's not really how android works

Comment: In order to do this, I believe you will have to break a lot of rules, but it is possible. I can't think of anything more elegant than passing extras in your intents back to the dashboard to save your location. Using startactivityforresult() and passing back activity names can work, but you may need more logic to put the user in the same spot they've left off. I would keep a history of all activities spawned from the dashboard, then use that for referencing the correct position based on the activity. Hopefully that helps the thought process on this.

Comment: @Falmarri I dont see how this "breaks" the way android works, the idea is to have the dashboard act as the android launcher does. When you are in a App, then click home to get out, and then click on the app icon again it jumps back to the activity it was at. That is exactly what I did, except I removed the icon from the launcher and put it in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you switch activities android's default action is to sort of pause or hold the activity in its state the user left it in last. I know there is a way to make it so that the state is not saved when switching activities but I cant remember it off the top of my head.